# What's one word to describe "I dont know what to believe in anymore"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

I ask because whenever I'm feeling this way I use "disillusioned" but I realize now that's not really the feeling

the context for the word or phrase is for in-general, eg, "I feel [word or phrase] with [everything or particular-thing]"

the answer should not include "disillusion" because that word implies an illusion has dropped away, and I'm looking for, eg, when we don't even know what's real anymore

a phrase is acceptable

Final important note: I acknowledge the words confused, bewildered, uncertain and their synonyms but they still fall short: **what I'm also looking for would describe how this world is purposefully making us feel this way**

Comment: Disillusioned is still a very valid term, meaning one is unsure of their beliefs, not their illusions.

Comment: Your question is too vague, you do not explain what this disappointment is cause by, what exactly you want the word to mean.

Comment: I agree. It's not clear what is meant. Is it that you don't have any higher values to believe in (God, moral principles, etc)? Or you don't know who is telling the truth and who is lying? Or you believe the entire world is an illusion and there is some value elsewhere? There are many possible words for different situations from [anomie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomie) to [maya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maya_(religion)) to [brain in a vat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain_in_a_vat). You could try philosophy SE if you are able to explain it better.

Comment: _Betrayed_ is often used in this context; and per your example, more specifically: "I feel betrayed by life". A religious person could say "by God." Although, I'm not sure if this is still too general and your question is open-ended as mentioned in the comments before.

Comment: "POLITICS!!!!!"

Answer (score 1):

"I don't know what to believe in anymore"

[Nonplussed](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nonplussed) If you are nonplussed, you feel confused and unsure how to react. It may also have this [meaning, (from Wiktionary)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nonplussed) (proscribed, US, informal) Unfazed, unaffected, or unimpressed. [from 20th c.]

[Iffy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/iffy) as in "feeling iffy".

[Ambivalent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ambivalent) as in "feeling ambivalent".

[Skeptical,](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/skeptical) having or expressing doubt about something (such as a claim or statement)

[Fragmented](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fragmented) as in "feeling fragmented".

[Quandary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/quandary) as in "a state of quandary" If you are in a quandary, you have to make a decision but cannot decide what to do.

Another candidate word is ["floored"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/floored). To cause one a great deal of shock, surprise, or disbelief.

Comment: All of these describe emotional states and not " not knowing what to believe".

Comment: I've voted so as to cancel the DV, banuyayi, as OP goes on to say 'I ask because whenever I'm feeling this way I use "disillusioned" but I realize now that's not really the feeling'.  OP has attracted two DVs already, probably because it's not clarified whether the emotional state or the cognitive position is being asked about. And yes, they usually overlap.

Comment: Thank you. I have majorly edited the answer. Pruned some words and added a few. I hope this answer is adequate to the task.